# Problem updating WINE

Tags: apt, updates, wine

I installed WINE to use ADE and now the updater wants to update it but when I tell it to proceed it tells me it requires installation of untrusted packages.

However, I have "https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ xenial main" checked under the "other software" tab of the "Software and Updates" settings menu. Is there another repository I need to add somewhere to update? Alternatively, as I am having no issues with WINE, is it possible to  mark it as "do not update"? (it took blood, sweat, tears and lots and lots of coffee to install so I don't want it to break!)

I have WINE version 3.0.4.

```
lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch:printing-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:printing-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch:security-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:security-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

Comment: wouldn't removing the ppa effectively accomplish this?

Comment: haha :) I'll draft an answer! \o/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could remove the PPA and as a result wine will no longer receive updates but at the same time has no incentive to be removed from your system unless you explicitly command it to with a terminal command.